# C# apply more than one filter to datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a list of filters that the user has input and I want to apply them to my `DataGridView`. What is the best way to apply all the filters to a `DataGridView`? My list of `ColumnFilters` is basically a list of strings which are broken into : `Column name, operand (=, >, < etc.)` and the value of the user input.

```
public void ApplyFilters(List<ColumnFilter> filters)
{
    if (filters.Count > 0))
    {
        foreach (ColumnFilter filter in filters)
        {
            BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource; 
            bs.Filter = string.Format("{0} {1} '{2}'", filter.ColumnName, filter.Operand, filter.Value);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bindingsource `Filter` supports `AND`, so the filters could be combined with something like:

```
bs.Filter  = string.Join(" AND ", filters.Select(filter=>string.Format("{0} {1} '{2}'", filter.ColumnName, filter.Operand, filter.Value).ToArray());
```

(Note: the foreach is not needed when using the above)

Comment: Can the same be made to work with just one filter? Otherwise I can put a simple check for that, but it would be great if all the logic was in one line.

Comment: Actually I am using .NET 3.5 so I might have a problem making this compile

Comment: It should work with just one filter. That's the beauty of string.join. If there's just one item in the enumeration, it doesn't add the separator (AND).

Comment: 3.5 has Linq, so that shouldn't be a problem. You might need to add a `using System.Linq` if Select isn't recognised, but it should be supported.

Comment: Ok I made it work, it just had to transform the inner part in .ToArray()

Comment: Ah, good, was just typing that. The string.join overload with an Enumerable was added in 4.0 . Glad you found it, I will alter the post too.